# Get Selected Value for server side drop down list in Vb.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I filled my server side drop down list using jQuery and i have to get this drop down value on server side i am using Vb.net.
One idea is that on button click save selected value in hidden field and get on server side but I want to know that is any way by which i can get this value directly without using hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to try Request.forms and check it

Answer (score 1):

Like Dhaval said you can use Request.Form.In my projects I have used it and it works through the use of a button.

In your markup

Add a button like this `

```
<asp:Button ID="IDButton" runat="server" CssClass="HiddenText" />
```

HiddenText is a simple css class with display set to none.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
```

Silently forcing a post back

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function SaveSelectedValueForLaterUse(selectedItem, selectedLabel) {
        __doPostBack('<%#IDButton.UniqueID%>', selectedItem + '|' +  selectedLabel);
         }
  </script>
```

In your jquery select function

```
 select: function (e, i) {
            SaveSelectedValueForLaterUse(i.item.val, i.item.label);
               }
```

Now enjoy the fruits of your hard work in code behind

```
 Protected Sub IDButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IDButton.Click
    Dim args As String() = Split(Request.Form("__EVENTARGUMENT"), "|", , CompareMethod.Text)
   //grab the id and use it
   Dim myid=args[0]
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i got data directly by using Request.Form(DrpGoingTo.UniqueID)